# ActionController::ParameterMissing in JobsController#update (param is missing or the value is empty: job)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this error whenever I try to make payment for a Jobs Advert on my application using '**Payola Stripe Payment Processor Integration**'

> param is missing or the value is empty: job

Before, I explain what I think could have raised the error, here are my codes.

[Here is the Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woHdC.png)

**development.log**

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: job):
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:53:in `job_params'
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:19:in `update'
```

**jobs_controller.rb**

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @jobs = Job.paid_ad
  end

  def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to @job if @job.paid?
  end

  def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    if !(@job.paid?)
      @job.update_attributes(stripeEmail: params[:stripeEmail],     payola_sale_guid: params[:payola_sale_guid])
      @job.update(job_params) unless @job.paid?
      redirect_to show_job_path(@job)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    if @job.save
      redirect_to preview_job_path(@job)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def preview
   @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to @job if @job.paid?
  end

  def payment
    @job = Job.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
    redirect_to job_path(@job) if @job.paid?
  end


  private

  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:title, :category, :location, :description, :to_apply, :email, :company_name, :website)
  end
end
```

I also defined a method in my model.

**job.rb**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

include Payola::Sellable

  validates :title,
            :category,
            :location,
            :description,
            :company_name,
            :website,
            :email,
            :to_apply,
            presence: true
  validates :title, length: { maximum: 75 }
  validates :description, length: { minimum: 300 }
  validates :to_apply, length: { maximum: 500 }

  validates_formatting_of :email, using: :email
  validates_formatting_of :website, using: :url

  before_validation :provide_name, :provide_permalink

  def self.paid_ad
    where.not('stripeEmail' => nil).where.not('payola_sale_guid' => nil).where('created_at > ?', 30.days.ago)
  end

  def paid?
    (!(self.stripeEmail == nil) && !(self.payola_sale_guid == nil))
  end


  private

  def provide_name
    self.name = 'FarFlung' if self.name == nil
  end

  def provide_permalink
    self.permalink = "#{ self.name } #{ SecureRandom.hex }".parameterize if self.permalink == nil
  end
end
```

Under the View I have this:

**\app\views\jobs\payment.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'shared/four_breaks' %>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <strong style="font-weight: bold; font-size:20px;">STEP 3 (OF 3): ENTER YOUR PAYMENT INFORMATION</strong>
      <%= render 'shared/two_breaks' %>
      <div class="lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        <%= simple_form_for @job,
                            html5: {
                                    class: 'payola-payment-form',
                                    'data-payola-base-path' => main_app.payola_path,
                                    'data-payola-product' => @job.product_class,
                                    'data-payola-permalink' => @job.permalink
                            } do |f| %>

            <p style="color:red"><span class="payola-payment-error"></span></p>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <label>Your email address
                  <input type="email" name="job[stripeEmail]" data-payola="email" value="<%= @job.email %>" />
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <label>Card number
                  <input type="text" data-stripe="number" />
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label>Exp Month
                  <input type="text" data-stripe="exp_month"/>
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label>Exp Year
                  <input type="text" data-stripe="exp_year"/>
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p><label>CVC Code
                  <input type="text" data-stripe="cvc"/>
                </label></p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <%= f.submit 'PAY AND DISPLAY AD NOW', class: 'button radius medium expand success' %>
              </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= render 'shared/two_breaks' %>
        <%= link_to (image_tag('big.png')) %>
        <%= render 'shared/four_breaks' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What I felt caused the problem**

What I felt cause this error is because am **using direct html** inside my *PaymentsView* with *input* tag.

```
<label>Your email address
  <input type="email" name="stripeEmail" data-payola="email" value="<%= @job.email %>" />
</label>
```

**Solution I used**

I changed the name attribute in my view to name="job[stripeEmail]" and it worked, but it saves nothing to my Jobs DB.

```
<label>Your email address
  <input type="email" name="job[stripeEmail]" data-payola="email" value="<%= @job.email %>" />
</label>
```

I really can't wrap my head around this. Kindly assist me. I will need stripeEmail to save in my DB, since it's one of the attributes that determines if a job is paid, before I show it on the index page. Am I missing something here, or is it that my Payola/Stripe configuration is wrong?

Comment: I have never used Payola before, but after I took a brief look at their document. I am not sure the thing you want to achieve here fits their way of handling payment or not. but anyway, can you provide the server log when you submit the form to just take a look what is happening in the controller?

Comment: something like this `Started POST "/tests" for ::1 at 2016-04-08 00:30:19 -0400
Processing by TestsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"/C7OhWFwkI7OEtVI82pWp1/IffIUVDLfwGPZfZJSBE05eo/YN8y4HfdIgRrvFYTArCRbAxzKnd7zDqdK3ENUYA==", "genre"=>"Pop"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "tests" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2016-04-08 04:30:19.514458"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-08 04:30:19.514458"]]
   (0.7ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/tests/3
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)`

Comment: If i use the solution pattern I stated, my server log is as follows:
`Started PATCH "/jobs/7" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-08 19:06:01 +0100
Processing by JobsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rvQephNSRqi270Cp9kr6zfPMxFv7TJWnz28KTBfk1iM=", "job"=>{"stripeEmail"=>"afolabiolaoluwa@gmail.com"}, "commit"=>"PAY AND DISPLAY AD NOW", "id"=>"7"}
  Job Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs"  WHERE "jobs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction`

Comment: `Job Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "jobs"  WHERE ("jobs"."permalink" = 'farflung-30ed8fe920dbb46b68fc3160dfd47c06' AND "jobs"."id" != 7) LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Unpermitted parameters: stripeEmail
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "jobs"  WHERE ("jobs"."permalink" = 'farflung-30ed8fe920dbb46b68fc3160dfd47c06' AND "jobs"."id" != 7) LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/jobs/7
Completed 302 Found in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)`

Comment: But if I use name="stripeEmail" attribute in my View, my server log is:
`Started PATCH "/jobs/7" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-08 19:23:25 +0100
Processing by JobsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rvQephNSRqi270Cp9kr6zfPMxFv7TJWnz28KTBfk1iM=", "stripeEmail"=>"afolabiolaoluwa@gmail.com", "commit"=>"PAY AND DISPLAY AD NOW", "id"=>"7"}
  Job Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs"  WHERE "jobs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  `

Comment: `Job Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "jobs"  WHERE ("jobs"."permalink" = 'farflung-30ed8fe920dbb46b68fc3160dfd47c06' AND "jobs"."id" != 7) LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "jobs" SET "stripeEmail" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "jobs"."id" = 7  [["stripeEmail", "afolabiolaoluwa@gmail.com"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-08 18:23:25.160243"]]
   (97.1ms)  commit transaction
Completed 400 Bad Request in 130ms`
And it save stripeEmail to DB but it raise the error in the posted Picture.

Comment: i have updated the answer for you, basically it's caused by your `job_params` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like the problem is here

`@job.update_attributes(stripeEmail: params[:stripeEmail],     payola_sale_guid: params[:payola_sale_guid])
@job.update(job_params) unless @job.paid?`

your `params` structure is `"job"=>{"stripeEmail"=>"afolabiolaoluwa@gmail.com"}`, so if you want to access the `stripeEmail`, you have to do

`@job.update_attributes(stripeEmail: params[:job][:stripeEmail], payola_sale_guid: params[:payola_sale_guid])`

but you can actually remove `@job.update_attributes(stripeEmail: params[:stripeEmail]`, you just need to add `:stripeEmail` and `:payola_sale_guid` to your `job_params` permit, then `@job.update(job_params)` will do the samething for you.

so you can change

`params.require(:job).permit(:title, :category, :location, :description, :to_apply, :email, :company_name, :website)`

to

`params.require(:job).permit(:title, :category, :location, :description, :to_apply, :email, :company_name, :website, :stripeEmail, :payola_sale_guid)`

## update

about the error you got in the posted picture, it is because in your form, you did not send any data wrapped by `job`, so there is nothing like `{"job": {foo: data}}` in your params, however in your controller, you called `job_params` which require `job`. so a simple fix will be

`@job.update(job_params) if params.has_key?(:job)`

Comment: Okay. I will try that. But what do you suggest about my view:
1. using direct html name="stripeEmail"
2. using name="job[stripeEmail]"
???

So that I can know what I will append your solution/suggestion to.

Comment: I suggest you use job[stripeEmail], just because the code will be more clean in your controller, but again I am not familiar with `Payola`, so I can't say this way is following their convention

Comment: surely I will do that. I might need your help too to click Research effort too, because this error is making me research more. 


If I understand this `@job.update(job_params) if params.has_key?(:job)` very well, you passed in a Ruby method `has_key?`, which returns True if the key/attributes are present in the given hash, and if True, it updates the Database Table attributes.
Haaaaa, Yes yes yes, **am sure this your simple fix will work**

Comment: I need "payola_sale_guid" too to be save on my database as it's also one of the points that determines if a Job Advert is paid for. My Payment Form works but it doesn't validate and I feel it's the reason I don't have "payola_sale_guid" in my database. I don't know what to do, and I have added all needed from Payola